# VoiceOver does not read all texts

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, voiceover, apple-tv

I'm working on a tvOS app and have the following issue. The app display numerous separate textual elements. When I start VoiceOver on the Apple TV, it reads a couple of elements but then stops eventually. It seems that it stops after some count of textual elements. Because when I reorder the content, the then first content is read correctly until it stops again after reading the first elements.

So my question is: is there a static limit of textual elements VoiceOver on AppleTV reads? And if so, can it be configured? Might it be some other issue that I did not think of?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I created a test app that contained two vertical stacks with each containing 10 text elements (inserting more than ten Texts would result in a compiler error) and VO stopped reading after the tenth element. So this seems to be the limit on tvOS as of now (tvOS 14.5).